# Processing GMap Api Responses

Tags: google-maps

I can't understand what the URL https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#Parsing mentions:

> As the exact format of individual responses with a web service request
>   is not guaranteed (some elements may be missing or in multiple
>   locations), you should never assume that the format returned for any
>   given response will be the same for different queries. Instead, you
>   should process the response and select appropriate values via
>   expressions. This section discusses how to extract these values
>   dynamically from web service responses.

What does it actually means there? Especially the line

> Instead, you should process the response and select appropriate values via
>   expressions

Does it mean to get certain value, we cannot just do

```
myJSONResult.results[0].address_components[0].long_name
```

for example, to get the name of the location that we're searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this means that you have to take care of the format that you have defined/specified and address the response (the data structure that comes) **based** on the defined/specified format.

For example, assume that you have a Ajax/JQuery function which transfers the data to the client.

```
 $.ajax({
          url: url_value,
          data: {
             format: 'desired_format'
          },
     contentType:
          error: function() {
             // if an error occurs
          },
          dataType: 'recieved_data_type',
          success: function(data) {
            //if the function retrieves the data 
          },
          type: GET/POST
});
```

Now if we analyze just this part (the important part send-receive):

```
contentType: "value",
dataType: "desired_value",
```

**contentType** is the header which you are sending to the server, defining/specifying a desired format
Example: sending JSON or XML

Some common examples (actual values):

- application/json; charset=utf-8
- application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
- text/plain

**dataType** is the response format your expect.
Example: receiving JSON, XML, HTML...

Some common examples (actual values):

- json
- xml
- html
- text

If you continue to read, the following will explain your cited paragraph even better:

> The parsing scheme you use depends on whether you are returning output
>   in XML or JSON. JSON responses, being already in the form of
>   Javascript objects, may be processed within Javascript itself on the
>   client;